# How to add a few Layouts to one main layout automatically Android Java

Tags: java, android, layout

I want to create scroll table (scroll vertical and horizontal).
I have main layout like this below and MainActivity with class which create new LinearLayout with a few new TextVievs. When I make a "loop for" new textViews are adding in one row but I want for example 10 rows with 5 columns (textviews).
I was looking a solution with creating loop in another loop, but then I have to create new Layout and then I have problem with findById because I can't create for example 100 new Layouts i XML.

```
package v1.projectTech;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity3 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

        createOneRow();


    }

    public void createLayouts() {
        int tmpnumberOfRows = MainActivity2.temp3.size();
        String[] numberOfLayouts = new String[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            LinearLayout linearLayout3_1_in = findViewById(R.id.layout4_1);

        }
     }

    public void createOneRow() {
//        int tmpNumberOfColumns = InformacjaOLokalizacji.numberOfColumns;

        LinearLayout linearLayout3_1_in = findViewById(R.id.layout3_1);
        LinearLayout linearLayout4_1_in = findViewById(R.id.layout4_1);//find the linear layout
        linearLayout4_1_in.removeAllViews();   //add this too

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {                                                        //looping to create 5 textviews
                TextView textView = new TextView(this);                                    //dynamically create textview
                textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(             //select linearlayoutparam- set the width & height
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 40));
                textView.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_VERTICAL);                       //set the gravity
                textView.setText("Textview: " + i);                                    //adding text
                linearLayout4_1_in.addView(textView);           //inflating :)

            }
    }
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout3"
    tools:context=".MainActivity3"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/layout3_1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <!--            row1-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/layout4_1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. It was a good direction but now I have one small problem. How to set a few parameters of object TextView in RecyclerView. When I'm trying to set text and set the background and one more parameter the system only sets text and doesn't change colour and size of TextView

Comment: @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterRecyclerView.ViewHolderRecyclerView holder, int position) {

            holder.textView2.setText(data1.get(position).get(1).toString());
            holder.textView3.setText(data1.get(position).get(2).toString());
            holder.textView4.setText(data1.get(position).get(3).toString());
            
            holder.textView2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("BLUE"));
            holder.textView3.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#54D66A"));
            holder.textView4.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("RED"));

Answer (score 0):

First off, you really don't want to do this-  its incredibly inefficient.  Instead, look into RecyclerView.  Its a way of efficiently creating large layouts like this without creating individual views for each row.

Secondly, if you do this (and even if you use RecyclerView really)-  the layout you want to create can be stored in its own XML file, inflated with LayoutInflater, and you don't need to worry about creating all the inidivdual view programatically.